# Headless chrome print to pdf hangs on certain sites when running on debian

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, debian

I am trying to use Headless chrome to print to pdf on debian 9.

On some sites it hangs and never returns with an error.
When trying to do the same on Windows 10 it works.

Example site: https://www.ynet.co.il/home/0,7340,L-8,00.html

Turning on logging does not reveal any relevant information.
I am assuming it has something to do with fonts but since it hangs and return no error i am not sure how to proceed.
Is there some to understand why it hangs?

Setup on debian:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install
```

Creating pdf on debian:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --displayHeaderFooter=false --print-to-pdf=result.pdf https://www.ynet.co.il/home/0,7340,L-8,00.html
```

Creating pdf on windows (need to install google chrome and change the path to it accordingly):

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --displayHeaderFooter=false --print-to-pdf=result.pdf https://www.ynet.co.il/home/0,7340,L-8,00.html
```